# Can't start scenebuilder on intellj for JavaFx on mac m1

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

At first I got a message saying failed to start scenebuilder, but now I just get a blank screen and don't know what to do.

[image: screen capture]

Comment: Alternative: You can see if the [standalone version](https://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/) works for you.

Comment: Share the "Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data" archive via https://uploads.jetbrains.com